# ungroup() before group_by()?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have seen many answers stating that `ungroup()` **must** follow every `group_by()`. However, I can't find the answer to one related question:

**When performing sequential calculations, each with a different group_by() -- is it necessary to `ungroup()` explicitly, or is `ungroup()` implied in the `group_by()`?**

```
with <- iris %>%
  group_by(Petal.Width) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup()

without <- iris %>%
  group_by(Petal.Width) %>%
  group_by(Species) %>%
  count() %>%
  ungroup()

identical(with, without)
# [1] TRUE
```

The answer **seems** to be that a mediating `ungroup()` is unnecessary. Am I missing anything?  Are there cases when there would be a difference?

Comment: As GregorThomas' answer conveys, the default is `.add=FALSE`, which means it always replaces the current grouping, so `group_by(var1) %>% group_by(var2) %>% group_by(var3)` just inefficiently calculates/stores/discards the grouping for each of `var1` and `var2`, and results in data that is only grouped by `var3`. If you're doing just one call to `mutate`/`summarize`, then you may prefer the `.by=` argument [added in `dplyr_1.1.0`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2022/11/dplyr-1-1-0-is-coming-soon/#temporary-grouping-with-by) for its brevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the help page is a good place to start. The `?group_by` help page describes the `.add` argument:

> `.add`
>
> When `FALSE`, the default, `group_by()` will override existing groups. To add to the existing groups, use `.add = TRUE`.

So, as long as you don't override `.add`'s default value of `FALSE`, you can skip the `ungroup()` immediately before a `group_by`. Any existing groups will be overridden.

Worth noting that since `dplyr` version 1.1.0, you can use the `.by` argument *inside* other functions like `mutate` and `summarize` which applies the grouping only for that command, and returns an ungrouped data frame. Generally, I much prefer this to `group_by()` and `ungroup()`.

Comment: Thanks for the perfectly clear answer.Indeed, I use group by manly for one-time mutates, so the `.by` tip is very useful!